# Inner Pageblock in a Pageblock

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need to create a Table with data inside a Pageblock on the right side of my inputs. The problems is that the Pageblock is not taking all the space. [image: Here an example]

The data are working so this is layout related only here is the code of the example page:

```
<apex:page controller="userSkillController">

    <style  type="text/css">
        .bPageBlock {width:100%;} 
    </style>
    <apex:form > 
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageblockSection title="Chat Type" collapsible="false" >
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="selectionBlock">
                    <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="100%">
                        <apex:panelGroup >
                            <apex:panelGrid columns="5">
                                <apex:selectList id="unselected_list" required="false" value="{!selected}" multiselect="true" size="11" style="width:100px">
                                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Disponibili}"/>
                                </apex:selectList>
                                <apex:panelGroup >
                                    <apex:commandButton value=">>" action="{!addUsers}" rerender="selectionBlock"/>
                                    <br/>
                                    <apex:commandButton value="<<" action="{!removeUsers}" rerender="selectionBlock"/>
                                </apex:panelGroup>
                                <apex:selectList id="selected_list" required="false" value="{!unselected}" multiselect="true" size="11" style="width:100px">
                                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Selezionati}"/>
                                </apex:selectList>
                                <apex:selectOption >
                                    <apex:commandButton id="update" value="Update"/>
                                    <apex:commandButton id="test" value="test"/>
                                    <apex:commandButton id="update2" value="Update2"/>
                                </apex:selectOption>
                            </apex:panelGrid>
                        </apex:panelGroup>

                        <apex:pageBlock title="Report Skill">
                            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!usersListSelezionati}" var="q" width="10px">
                                <apex:column >
                                    <apex:facet name="header">Skill</apex:facet>
                                </apex:column>
                                <apex:column >
                                    <apex:facet name="header">Chat Requests</apex:facet>
                                </apex:column>
                                ...
                                ...
                            </apex:pageBlockTable>
                        </apex:pageBlock>

                    </apex:panelGrid>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageblockSection> 

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how an apex:pageBlockSectionitem works. Page block section items are design to align some labels with their inputs.

However, I managed to do what you need with some styles and by removing the page block section items.

The style added matches the two columns of the main page block section. With the :nth-child(2) selector, I set the width of the table to 100% to fill the remaining space.

```
<apex:page controller="userSkillController">

    <style  type="text/css">
        .bPageBlock .detailList td.dataCol {
            width: auto;
        }
        .bPageBlock .detailList td.dataCol:nth-child(2) {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <apex:form > 
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageblockSection title="Chat Type" collapsible="false" >
                            <apex:panelGrid columns="5">
                                <apex:selectList id="unselected_list" required="false" value="{!selected}" multiselect="true" size="11" style="width:100px">
                                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Disponibili}"/>
                                </apex:selectList>
                                <apex:panelGroup >
                                    <apex:commandButton value=">>" action="{!addUsers}" rerender="selectionBlock"/>
                                    <br/>
                                    <apex:commandButton value="<<" action="{!removeUsers}" rerender="selectionBlock"/>
                                </apex:panelGroup>
                                <apex:selectList id="selected_list" required="false" value="{!unselected}" multiselect="true" size="11" style="width:100px">
                                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Selezionati}"/>
                                </apex:selectList>
                                <apex:selectOption >
                                    <apex:commandButton id="update" value="Update"/>
                                    <apex:commandButton id="test" value="test"/>
                                    <apex:commandButton id="update2" value="Update2"/>
                                </apex:selectOption>
                            </apex:panelGrid>

                        <apex:pageBlock title="Report Skill">
                            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!usersListSelezionati}" var="q" width="10px">
                                <apex:column >
                                    <apex:facet name="header">Skill</apex:facet>
                                </apex:column>
                                <apex:column >
                                    <apex:facet name="header">Chat Requests</apex:facet>
                                </apex:column>
                                ...
                                ...
                            </apex:pageBlockTable>
                        </apex:pageBlock>

            </apex:pageblockSection> 

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm editing this into my code to check it out. Can you explain me how the style works?

Comment: I edited my answer to explain the styles.

Comment: I checked my code with your suggestion and now everything is fine. Thank you